# Retrieving the value of Dynamically Created elements

Tags: javascript, html

i Have created a HTML form , in this form when i Click on a button it creates input text fields based on a predefined criteria , this works fine .
now when i try and retrieve the value entered in those created text fields using alert i am not able to do so .

i have two questions

1. What is the best way to retrieve inputs from the dynamically created text fields?
2. can you tell me why the code i have written does not work

HTML code

```
<BODY>
<FORM>
    <BR/>
    <div align = "center">
        <br /><br />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Click To Enter Values" onclick="getkeywords()"/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" id="d_div">
        <form name="permavalues" id="d_form">
        </form>
        <br/> <br/>
    </div>
</FORM>
```

THe javascript code that i am using is this :

```
function getkeywords() {
    var index_array = new Array();
    var myString = "one and a two and a three = $ and four = $ and five = $";
    var splitresult = myString.split(" ");

    for(i = 0; i < splitresult.length; i++)
    {
        if (splitresult[i] == "$" && i > 1 ) //retireving the keywords..
        {   
            add(splitresult[i-2]);
        }
    }
}
```

The add function which is called in getkeywords:

```
function add(s) {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", s);
    element.setAttribute("name", s);
    element.setAttribute("id", s);

    var foo = document.getElementById("d_form");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    alert("Value=" + document.getElemebtById(s).value);
}
```

I think that i must have a mistake with `element.setAtrribute("id",s);`

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `alert("Value=" + document.getElemebtById(s).value);` must be `alert("Value=" + document.getElementById(s).value);`

Comment: oh , i must missed it...is the logic correct i am more concerned with the  logic i have used . here i am  setting the value attribute to s , however when the texts are displayed in the webpage and user eneters some input , how do i retrieve that ? will it be stored in store property ?

Comment: You can always retrieve the user inputted value the same manner as you are displaying it right now. Select the element by id and retrieve the value. `document.getElementById(s).value`. If you use jQuery you can at the end run through all your inputs to process them but that of course depends on what you're planning to do with your page.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is you can't put form inside another form. Please remove you HTML code line 2 and line 13.

Another problem is your typo, as IvanL said.

Other code are fine.

Give you fully tested work code as below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
<script language="javascript">
function getkeywords() {
    var index_array = new Array();
    var myString = "one and a two and a three = $ and four = $ and five = $";
    var splitresult = myString.split(" ");

    for(i = 0; i < splitresult.length; i++)
    {
        if (splitresult[i] == "$" && i > 1 ) //retireving the keywords..
        {   
            add(splitresult[i-2]);
        }
    }
}
function add(s) {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", s);
    element.setAttribute("name", s);
    element.setAttribute("id", s);

    var foo = document.getElementById("d_form");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    alert("Value=" + document.getElementById(s).value);
}
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
    <BR/>
    <div align = "center">
        <br /><br />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Click To Enter Values" onclick="getkeywords()"/>
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add('tt')">
    </div>
    <div align="center" id="d_div">
        <form name="permavalues" id="d_form">
        </form>
        <br/> <br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to retrieve inputs from the dynamically created
>   text fields?

I would use JQuery to traverse the form for all text input elements and retrieve their respective values.

Alternatively, you could give each of the text fields a common name like "txt_" and then append an incremental ID  to the string (I.E. -- txt_1, txt_2, txt_3, ...) then programmatically iterate over your form fields that match until you've reached a value that represents the total number of available form fields. That value could be a javascript integer.

For example...

```
$("form input[type='text']").each( function() 
{ 
    // gets text value for each field in the form
    var textFieldValue = this.value;

    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the Jquery code for getting All Input Value.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form#d_form input[type="text"]').each(
    function()
    {
         alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```